# Nginx remembering old subdomain

Tags: nginx, caching, subdomain

I am having a weird issue. My ubuntu server is still remembering an old subdomain, even though the configuration files is deleted, both symlink and the original one.

The nginx service is restarted, and the health is just fine as seen below:

```
website:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Why on earth is the old subdomain still accessible? there is no specific DNS settings for the subdomain, all I have is

```
*.domain.com | ip
www.domain.com | ip
```

**This is the contents of nginx:**

```
website:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ls
- is empty

website:/etc/nginx/sites-available# ls
- is empty
```

**Nginx conf:**

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I have tried to disable nginx caching, but still it's like its remembering the old subdomain somehow. Any experience on this?

Comment: `*.domain.com` is a subdomain. Whats in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`?

Comment: @sur.la.route I have updated my answer :)

Comment: It looks like your logs are in access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log and error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log; After your access the site, does it say anything interesting in those logs to verify that you were in fact directed to this server?